# Prolog setOf with Multiple Predicates

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

In my prolog database, I have below facts:

```
played('Sharon rose', piano).
played('Robert Kay', piano).
played('Kelvin Cage', drums).
singer('Robert Kay').
band_leader('Sharon rose').
```

I want to print out all the names uniquely as a single list.

Below is my query using setof and the output:

```
setof(X, (played(X,_);singer(X);band_leader(X)), Output).

Output = ['Robert Kay','Sharon rose'] ? ;

Output = ['Kelvin Cage'] ? ;

Output = ['Robert Kay','Sharon rose']

yes
```

However, the output isn't what I want.
I want it to print out the names uniquely as a list.

Comment: Did you intend `Drums` to be `Drums` or `drums`?

Comment: It’s drums (small letter “d”, not variable as “Drums”), was a typo. Thanks for noting that. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get multiple answers due to the anonymous variable in the goal argument of `setof/3`. Try instead:

```
?- setof(X, Y^(played(X,Y);singer(X);band_leader(X)), Output).
```

Comment: I missed the concept of the anonymous variable in respect to the argument setof/3. Thanks, it's okay now.